# Converting a MongoDB Query String with Datetime field into Dict in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, datetime, dictionary, serialization

I have a string as follows,
**`s= "query : {'$and': [{'$or': [{'Component': 'pfr'}, {'Component': 'ng-pfr'}, {'Component': 'common-flow-table'}, {'Component': 'media-mon'}]}, {'Submitted-on': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 21, 0, 0)}}, {'Submitted-on': {'$lte': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 28, 0, 0)}}]}
"`** which is a MongoDB query stored in a string.How to convert it into a Dict or JSON format in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is not standard, so you need a hack to get it.

```
import json
s = " query : {'names' :['abc','xyz'],'location':'India'}"
key, value = s.strip().split(':', 1)
r = value.replace("'", '"')
data = {
    key: json.loads(r)
}
```

From your comment: the `datetime` gives problems. Then I present to you the hack of hacks: the `eval` function.

```
import datetime
import json
s = " query : {'names' :['abc','xyz'],'location':'India'}"
key, value = s.strip().split(':', 1)
# we can leave out the replacing, single quotes is fine for eval
data = {
    key: eval(value)
}
```

NB `eval` -especially on unsanitized input- is **very** unsafe.

NB: hacks will be broken, in the first case for example because a value or key contains a quote character.

Comment: It throws an error as follows  `No JSON object could be decoded` at line `key:json.loads(r)`. I tried using **simple json** to have detailed error notification but unfortunately that module is not available and i don't have permissions to add modules

Comment: I found that its the datetime object that causes the issue